# MySQL want non-primary key that auto-increments with SELECT INTO

Tags: mysql

I have my_table of names. I want to select these sorted by name and insert them into another table my_table2 in this order. My_table2 has a field "display_order" that should be sequential with respect to the order of names.

```
insert into my_table2(display_order, name)
select something_special(), name from my_table
order by name;
```

such that display_order is 1,2,3.. following name order.

Is this possible with a single select, i.e. NOT a loop:

```
  loop through my_table1 sorted by name:
      insert name, display_order into my_table2
      increment display_order
```

It's innodb

Why I want this:

The my_table select is actually much more complex involving various user search parameters. I want to be able to do this search once, and then save the results into my_table 2. Getting data out of my_table2 is then much quicker and easier. And, yes, I know that my_table2 is not updated as data is altered in my_table. That's as it should be.

Comment: Why do you want this?

Comment: Have you tried using a user variable in the SELECT, that gets incremented for every row …?

Comment: Not sure what you mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question properly, you need something like

```
insert into my_table2(display_order, name)
select @a:=@a+1, name 
from my_table
join (select @a :=0) b ON (1=1)
order by name;
```

To be absolutely sure that the variable incremented according to `order by` (I don't remember if mysql guarantees when exactly variable is calculated) you may want to rewrite it like :

```
insert into my_table2(display_order, name)
select @a:=@a+1, a.name
from 
(
    select  name 
    from my_table
    order by name
 )a
 join (select @a :=0) b ON (1=1)
```

Comment: That's exactly what I wanted. I tried the second one and it worked. Thanks.